# Charset of a textarea, keyword not recognized

Tags: javascript, regex, encoding

I have an editor it's called [editarea](http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/) and it should work as an editor for programming languages to be embedded in a web page; but we are using it as an editor for other stuff. As it's exp'lained in the manual of editarea we've built a new syntax file, but it contains special characters, cause the syntax it has to recognize contains italian words. This below is some snapshot of the syntax file:

```
    ,'KEYWORDS' : {
     'feelings' : [
        "emozioni","gioia","felicit\xE0", etc.
```

And these are the regular expressions:

```
    ,'REGEXPS' : {
        'lemmas' : {
        'search' : "()(#[A-Za-z0-9'èéòàìù]*)()"
        //'search' : "()(#[A-Za-z0-9'èéòàìù\s]+#)()"
        ,'class' : 'lemmas'
        ,'modifiers' : 'g'
        ,'execute' : 'before'
    },
```

As you can see the letters with accent are expressed with a code in the "keyword" and without the code in the "regular expression". The problem is that the words that ends with accent letter are not "colorized" in the righ way if they're typed alone. If you type a letter after the accent then they get recognized (but in this case they shouldn't be recognized as word but as lemmas with the regular expression).
This error is quite confusing.
I tryed encoding and decoding the input of the text area and the arguments of the colorize_text function usign those functions:

```
function encode_utf8(s) {
  return unescape(encodeURIComponent(s));
}

function decode_utf8(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
}
```

But nothing seem to change.
If anyone has understood the problem better than me (i can't understand why it colorize the text rightly when i add a character to the word with accent) then please explain to me in easy language.
Thank you for the effort.
Agnese

Comment: If you expect some answer, reduce code, shorten your question, please :)

Comment: ok, changed, i hope it is more readable now. Agnese

Comment: Why exactly do you need to enter texts in syntax files as encoding specific (ISO-8859-1?) hexadecimal codes rather that just typing the actual text? It's not clear either what encoding your site uses (UTF-8?). But if you use the same encoding everywhere you shouldn't need those hacks.